# How to move a JFrame file inside a folder to another folder in netbeans 13?

Tags: java, copy-paste, netbeans-13

I want to use my "Final_Frame.java" in my "SampleFrameProject.java", sort of like interconnecting it by creating a "Final_Frame" object and then typing the "this.show()".

[image]

However, an error message appears, saying that "package com.toedter.components does not exist." That is the only error I've seen; I'm confident that my "Final Frame.java" is functioning well before I copy-paste it, hence I knew the issue was caused by my copy-pasting.

[image]

Btw all of the error is pointing to JCalender, and JComponents, I'm pretty sure I followed the instructions while installing them. They are working just fine before I move the "Final_Frame.java", but after I move it, it began to show errors. So is there any way for me to copy-paste it correctly? or are there any methods to call "Final_Frame.java" inside my "SampleFrameProject.java" without copy-pasting?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/package.html) is a fundamental concept in Java. It is nothing but a namespace for the Java source file, reflecting the directory (folder) structure of your project after the `src/main/java` directory.

package is usually defined at the **first line** of the file. For example, given the directory structure from your root directory `mavenproject2`, the directory structure inside if it is `src/main/java/com/foo/bar/FinalJava.java`, then the corresponding `package` defined will be

```java
package com.foo.bar;

// imports

public class FinalJava {
// the content of class
}
```

For your case, it would seem that you have copied `com/toedter/components/FinalFrame.java` from the `Hotel_Management_System` project (which already has defined a line `package com.toedter.components` in the file) to another project `mavenproject2` which has a different directory structure (which is not clear in your question).

The solution would be to modify the package line according to your directory structure then it would solve the error.

Personally, I would suggest to learn some basics in Java, take some tutorials, or at least write some simple Java console applications before diving into GUI applications.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I've been learning java for about a month, and the reason I'm learning GUI is because that's what we're working on at school right now (I also feel like we are too fast pace)